# ISO 8601 format JJJJMMTT alias/script Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to implement a dat2iso command as a script or as an alias, which accepts a date in German format DD.MM.YYYY as a parameter and outputs the date in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format YYYYMMDD the output (to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)).

Examples (as an alias or as a script in the system path):

Outputs:

```
$ dat2iso 30.09.2021
20210930

$ dat2iso 01.01.2022
20220101

$ dat2iso 03/10/2021
Error!   <-- Because the separator was. required.

$ dat2iso 03.10.21
Error!   <-- Because the year YYYY was prescribed with four digits.

$ dat2iso 32.09.2021
Error!   <-- Denn einen 32. gibt es nicht.

$ dat2iso 30.13.2021
Error!   <-- Because there isn't any 13th month.
```

I have come so far to change the format, but I can’t figure the rest, but I’m still working on it:

```
echo 30.09.2021 | awk -F '.' {'printf "%s%s%s\n",$3,$2,$1'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very verbose solution, but it checks for your given exemptions:

```
cat << EOF > dat2iso
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "\$1" == "" ]];then echo -e "NO INPUT. Exiting."; exit 1 ;fi

echo \$1 | awk -F '.' '/\//{ print "Input Error."; exit(1) }
   \$1>31{ print "Too many days."; exit(1) }
   \$2>12{ print "Too many months."; exit(1) }
   \$3!~/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/{ print "Not enough year digits."; exit(1) }
   { print \$3\$2\$1 }'
EOF

chmod +x dat2iso

$ ./dat2iso 09.12.2021
20211209
```

Comment: [[ "\$1" == "" ]] what exactly do that?

Comment: Checks for no input. You can test it with a blank ‘./dat2iso’

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

dat2iso(){
    if  [[ $1 =~ ^([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{4})$ ]]; then
        local date="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if  date -d "$date" >& /dev/null; then
            echo "$date"
        else
            echo "Invalid date value [$date]" >&2
        fi
    else
        echo "Invalid format of input [$1]. Correct format [DD.MM.YYYY]" >&2
    fi
}

dat2iso 30.09.2021
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe, but when i remove the date in the script and put a random date, it come allways Invalied format of input :(

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: i mean, now we have in the script a date, but i just want to use the script for manul input. 
for example : dat2sio 03.12.2032

Comment: `dat2iso 03.12.2032` gives `20321203`. Is that NOT what you expected ?

Comment: yes, but i saved the script and i when i run it, it gives me that error

Comment: Double check how you ran the script. Also, run `echo $BASH_VERSION` to get bash version.

Comment: I have finnely, got my result ,,,,thanks Philippe ,,,, best man :)